# Create a dynamic ng-model for an input

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

How can I make the `ng-model` of an input dynamic?

**Static ng-model:**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myModel.firstName" />
```

**Dynamic ng-model:**

```
$scope.myInputs = [{ key: "firstName"}, { key: "lastName" }];

<div ng-repeat="input in myInputs">
  <input type="text" ng-model="myModel[input.key]" />
</div>
```

The `myModel[input.key]` does not seem to be calculating correctly.

Comment: assuming its to edit the input object `ng-model="input.key"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `myInputs[input.key]`, `input.key` is not the index. So you cannot access expected value.

You can either

```
<div ng-repeat="input in myInputs">
  <input type="text" ng-model="input.key" />
</div>
```

Or

```
<div ng-repeat="input in myInputs track by $index">
  <input type="text" ng-model="myInputs[$index].key" />
</div>
```